# Find conditional extremum of $f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4$ with condition $(x - 1)^3 - y^2 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

> Find conditional extremum of $f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4$ with condition $(x - 1)^3 - y^2 = 0$

I tried to use Lagrange multipliers:
$$L= x^4 + y^4 + \lambda(x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 - y^2)$$

I derived the system

$\begin{cases}
4x^3 + 3\lambda x^2 - 6\lambda x + 3\lambda  = 0\\
4y^3 - 2\lambda y = 0\\
(x - 1)^3 - y^2 = 0
\end{cases}$

So, one solution is $y = 0$, $x = 1$, but $\lambda$ could by arbitrary. So I don't know how to handle this case.

The other solution is $y^2 = \frac{\lambda}{2}$, and for $x$, I can't express it $x$ in terms of $\lambda$.

Can you help me finish the problem?

Comment: The curve has a cusp at (1,0),

Comment: Also, there are no constrained optima except at the cusp. Suggest you draw a graph of $y^2 = (x-1)^3,$ and, say in the first quadrant, some representative gradient vectors of $x^4 + y^4.$ You will see that these are never orthogonal to the cubic curve

Comment: If $y^2 = \frac{\lambda}{2}$, then you can plug that into your third equation to get $(x - 1)^3 - \frac{\lambda}{2} = 0$.

Comment: $y=0,x=1$ doesn't seem to satisfy the first equation so there is no extremum here.

Comment: @Reese Yeah, but that gives $4\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{\lambda}{2}} + 1\right)^3 + 3\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{\lambda}{2}} + 1\right)^2\frac{\lambda}{2} - 6\lambda \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{\lambda}{2}} + 1\right) + 3\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cusp at (1,0).

[image]

Now, consider the first quadrant, where the gradient vector of $x^4 + y^4$ has both components positive; the $x$ partial is positive, so is the $y$ partial derivative. Such a vector cannot be orthogonal to the curve. Indeed, you wrote it as $(x-1)^3 - y^2,$ the gradient is $\langle 3 (x-1)^2, - 2 y \rangle, $ on the portion of the curve in the first quadrant the $x$ partial is positive but the $y$ partial negative. This cannot be parallel to the other gradient vector, $\langle 4x^3, 4 y^3 \rangle.$ Also, as you can see, $x^4 + y^4$ is actually unbounded on the curve. Just let $x = 1 + t^2, y = t^3$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$